# c# windows library running under Linux

Tags: c#, cross-platform

I have a library that was created on Windows. In the library, I try to access a file that is marked in the project as content / copy if newer. For example:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"projectpath\testfile.txt");
```

This works fine on windows; however, as soon as I run it on Linux, it fails - because it's expecting:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"projectpath/testfile.txt");
```

How can I make this call agnostic of platform, or sensitive to it (so I can maybe put a `#if` check in)?

Comment: `Path.Combine`? `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`? (but usually: prefer `Path.Combine`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `/` - it works fine on Windows and other platforms:

```
 string text = File.ReadAllText(@"projectpath/testfile.txt");
```